# Using app script to send data from google sheets to firestore cloud

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to send data from google spreadsheet to firestore database but I don't know the header for each field , so I want to take the field names from the google sheets header column dynamically (first row of google sheets) .Below is the code I used. how to add the field names dynamically from the sheet itself.

```
function DBinsert() {
   const email = "xxxxxxxx.gserviceaccount.com";
   const key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
   const projectId = "db";
   var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);
   
// get document data from ther spreadsheet
   var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = sh1.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
   // get the last row and column in order to define range
   var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); // get the last row
   var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); // get the last column
   var dataSR = 2; // the first row of data
   // define the data range
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);
   // get the data
   var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
   // get the number of length of the object in order to establish a loop value
   var sourceLen = sourceData.length;
   // Loop through the rows
     for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
       if(sourceData[i][1] !== '') {
         var data = {};
           data.name = sourceData[i][0];
           data.age = sourceData[i][1];
           data.place = sourceData[i][2];
           data.address = sourceData[i][3];   
           firestore.createDocument("testsheet",data);
   }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the field name of the JSON data dynamically based on the header value?

Comment: Exactly  @MoniqueG. Instead of setting the data.name I want to set the header value instead. I am trying to develop an automated script that takes each spreadsheet and puts in the collection on a daily basis . so each spreadsheet might have different headers.

Comment: Then, you can try to use this approach: 
1. Read the header and store into an array. For example: headers[]
2. When setting the data, use the following syntax:
data[headers[0]] = sourceData[i][0];

Through this, you can already set the header dynamically.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to know it worked and it helped you, @SarijaJanardh!